# "Dereference" elements in ...interface{} function arguments

Tags: go

I have a logger that works fine, but produces quite some overhead in regard to memory allocation. Below `Debug()` function is not printing on purpose, because `logOutputLevel` isn't high enough.

```
var logOutputLevel = 2
func Debug(s string, args ...interface{}) {
    if logOutputLevel > 1 { return }
    fmt.Printf(s, args...)
}
```

Still that method produces quite some allocs when passing values to it. It doesn't produce heavy allocs when passing pointers to it. See the following benchmarks:

```
func BenchmarkLog(b *testing.B) {
    x := "abc"
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Debug("test %s", x)
    }
}

func BenchmarkLogRef(b *testing.B) {
    x := "abc"
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Debug("test %s", &x)
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
BenchmarkLog-8          50000000            43.1 ns/op        16 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkLogRef-8       500000000            3.17 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Now that's all nice and I'm trying to rework the `Debug()` method to accept one string and unlimited pointer arguments only. At a later point I would like to 'dereference' all arguments and pass them to `fmt.Printf()` if the loglevel is high enough.

How can I achieve this? Is there a specific language idiom for "only pointers"? I assume that `...*interface{}` means a pointer to an `interface{}` (and not any values should be a pointer).

Comment: There are no references in Go. What is your question? What you are trying to do is impossible to enforce.

Comment: There are no such things as "references" in go, pointers are values too. If the evaluation or allocation of the arguments is a problem, you need to use a conditional. See the `glog` package for example: https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog#Verbose

Comment: @Volker Old habit... I‘ve meant pointers ofc. Thanks for the hint. I‘ve corrected the question.

Comment: pointer to interface almost never makes any sense.

Comment: You cannot prevent those allocations in your library, at least not with an ergonomic API; accepting closures that return the values would work, for example, but is annoying to use. That's why almost all logging libraries have something like `func IsDebug() bool` that may be called by the user to prevent evaluating expensive arguments unnecessarily: [logrus](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#IsLevelEnabled), [zap](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#Logger.Check), [logxi](https://godoc.org/github.com/mgutz/logxi/v1#DefaultLogger.IsDebug).

Comment: If you're willing to make 'debugging' a compile-time (rather than runtime) concept, you can completely optimize away your `debug()` calls with build flags. See [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/09/28/using-build-to-switch-between-debug-and-release).

Comment: @Flimzy As far as I understand this will make the function not printing at all. I just tried that one, but the Debug() func is still having the alloc overhead, even though it is completely empty.

Comment: @xsigndll just wondering, are the allocation also happening if you discard the argument variables of the empty func using `_`? E.g. `func debug(_ string, _ ...interface{}) {}`

Comment: @mkopriva It still allocs, yes. Good idea though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent the allocations is to not do them in the first place.

This is usually done by putting the debug statement in a conditional block before it's evaluated:

```
if logOutputLevel > 1 {
    Debug("test: %s", x)
}
```

Which is how most logging packages handle it. See the [glog `Verbose` type](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog#Verbose) for example.

You can use build tags to conditionally compile the `Debug` function, and ignore the arguments altogether. This isn't guaranteed by the language spec to not allocate, but it is an optimization that the compiler could possibly make in the future, if the current performance it acceptable. Using two separate files, you can switch between the `Debug` implementations at compile time:

debug.go

```
// +build debug

package main

import "log"

func Debug(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf(fmt, args...)
}
```

release.go

```
// +build !debug

package main

func Debug(_ string, _ ...interface{}) {}
```

Comment: It allocs still (even with `_`), so I ended up using the first version: Using a `func IsDebug()` in front of every `Debug()`. It feels aweful still, but I think I'll have to accept it as answer.

Comment: @xsigndll, hmm, you're right. I swear I've tested that before, let me try some things.

Comment: @xsigndll: I must have been tried it once without the variadic argument. I changed the wording a bit and left the suggestion in there for those who may want to try it.